# Change style element of child to display unique div on hover of parent page element 36 occurences

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 36 pictures. I currently have a verbose and repetitive approach using 72 ids and 72 css lines. I think it could be replaced by one jQuery function specifying children (or similar) but I can't figure it out.

When hovering on a given thumbnail I want a custom div with custom text and resized img to show floating over the center of the screen.

I successfully accomplished my goals in a brute-force way: Not DRY at all

```
<div class="left-pcontainer">
<div class="make-fixed">
<div id="art">
  <span class="subject-title">express - make stuff</span>

  <span id="art1">
    <img   src="p-imgs/candyCaneCircle.png" >
       <div id="smack1" class="smack-in-middle">
        <img  src="p-imgs/candyCaneCircle.png" style="width:100%;">
        <p style="float:right;">Hello World I love you!</p>  
        <p>Hello Candy Cane I love you!</p>  
        <p>You taste great</p>  
        <p>Why only in December?</p>  

      </div>      
  </span>          

  <span id="art2"> 
    <img  src="p-imgs/PirateCircle.png" >
      <div id="smack2" class="smack-in-middle">
          <img  src="p-imgs/PirateCircle.png" >
          <p>Yarr! Piracy!</p> 
          <p>and a bottle of rum</p> 
          <p>Land Ahoy</p> 
      </div> 
  </span>
```

repeat above two blocks with 2 unique ids each 34 more times, additionally with two lines of css for each of the 36 items. Of course I need the 36 divs but not the 72 ids and repetitive css. I'd like to be able to adjust size editing 2 classes/ids not 72.

css:

```
#art{
  background-color: rgb(142, 169, 186);
}
#art img{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
}
.smack-in-middle{
  position:fixed;
  left:300px;
  top:100px;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}
art1:hover #smack1{ display: block; }
#art1:hover #smack1 img{width:100%;}
#art2:hover #smack2{ display: block;}
#art2:hover #smack2 img{width:100%;}
#art3:hover #smack3{ display: block;}
#art3:hover #smack3 img{width:100%;}
#art4:hover #smack4{ display: block;}
#art4:hover #smack4 img{width:100%;}
#art5:hover #smack5{ display: block;}
#art5:hover #smack5 img{width:100%;}
/*and so on 31 more times*/
```

I would like to find something like my attempt below

```
$('.art-item').children().hover(function(){
$(this).fadeIn(500);
}, function(){
(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

I also somehow deal with the sticky issue of re-sizing the pictures to 100% to over-ride their id specified 30% somehow.

my attempt at jQuery hides the thumbnail (which I don't want) and does not show the hidden div.  I've also tried next() etc with no luck finding the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#art {
    background-color: rgb(142, 169, 186);
}
.art-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1%;
}
.art-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.smack-in-middle {
    position:fixed;
    left:300px;
    top:100px;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.art-item:hover .smack-in-middle {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div id="art"> <span class="subject-title">express - make stuff</span>
 <span class="art-item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
       <div class="smack-in-middle">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        <p style="float:right;">Hello World I love you!</p>  
        <p>Hello Candy Cane I love you!</p>  
        <p>You taste great</p>  
        <p>Why only in December?</p>  

      </div>      
  </span>
 <span class="art-item"> 
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <div class="smack-in-middle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
          <p>Yarr! Piracy!</p> 
          <p>and a bottle of rum</p> 
          <p>Land Ahoy</p> 
      </div> 
  </span>

</div>
```

I added a class of `art-item` to each parent span tag with an id of `art-X`. Also, applied the `width: 30%` and `margin: 1%` to these elements instead of the image.

Instead of toggling between `display: none` and `display: block` on hover, I am toggling between `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` - this will allow you to create some nice transitions and easing.

By toggling opacity, you need to modify the `pointer-events` attribute to ensure no one is able to select any of the child elements of `.smack-in-middle`

Comment: Exactly what I hoped for an more.. and interesting that it's so possible, even with transitions with CSS .Wow,  that was super! both you and Paul were so quick with it too.  I really appreciate the community I'm joining.

Comment: I want to add that you showed me how to swap the widths to make the change work without resorting to using id's to trump the first id I used to set the 30% img... that was something I needed.  Thanks for picking up some artifact inline styling I was experimenting with on some items too.

Comment: @Tom22 you bet! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Give "art1", "art2" etc. a class as well as an ID, eg. "art-item".

Then you can simply assign the properties to that class, so…

```
<span id="art1" class="art-item">
    <img src="p-imgs/candyCaneCircle.png" >
    <div id="smack1" class="smack-in-middle">
      <img  src="p-imgs/candyCaneCircle.png" style="width:100%;">
      <p style="float:right;">Hello World I love you!</p>  
      <p>Hello Candy Cane I love you!</p>  
      <p>You taste great</p>  
      <p>Why only in December?</p>
    </div>      
</span> 

#art{
  background-color: rgb(142, 169, 186);
}
#art img{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.smack-in-middle{
  position:fixed;
  left:300px;
  top:100px;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}

.art-item:hover .smack-in-the-middle{ display: block; }
.art-item:hover .smack-in-the-middle img{ width:100%; }
```

Comment: Thumbs up for using CSS instead of JS. I have a very similar approach that I'll post.

Comment: Great answer ,  I'm not sure how CSS understands not to show all items with the same class when I hover on one(that happened to me when I was trying to do something like this..but I bet I didn't have nested spans at the time) thank you for taking the time.  I noticed I could get rid of all the ids too which was one of my goals.  My artifact of 100% width style inline through off my hope to fix that another way.  Thanks again

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give you a thumbs up but I tried.  I'll come back when I have 15 points

Comment: Glad you got what you needed! Keep on at it.